# Configure Pylance to stop prefixing project directory on import auto-complete

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

When working in a Git repository where my Python/Django source is in a subfolder `{$workspace}/app`, as seen below.

- project/

  - *.vscode/*
  - *.git/*
  - **app/** -- the app source code (not a Python module)
  - *docs/*
  - *.gitignore*
  - *LICENSE*

The problem is that VSCode adds an incorrect `app.` prefix when auto-generating import statements. For example, it will generate `app.core` when the actual project module is `core`. Also, there isn't an `__init__.py` in the `/app` directory.

I have read that I can open a workspace in the `app/` directory, but the project repository is one directory above the app source and I sometimes need to make changes at the project root level.

I have tried the following items in `settings.json`, which don't seem correct when all I want to do is configure the primary auto-complete and analysis paths.

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/app",
    ],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/app",
    ],
{
```

How can I get VSCode to stop treating the project `/app` directory as a Python module?

Comment: please provide a [mre]. you haven't provided .py files to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ths issue isn't related to any particular .py file. It is about VSCode looking in the wrong directory when a project is open in the repository root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the file structure in your question, open the **project** as a workspace. *settings.json* should be like this

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./app",
    ],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "./app",
    ],
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, been pulling my hair out on this one